# Loop for Extracting Detailed HTML tables from multiple webpages into Excel

Tags: javascript, vba, extract, imacros, html-content-extraction

I would like to extract info from each page on the http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/suchergebnis.aspx when I go into details for each auto (after clicking "Suchen" (eng. Search)).

E.g. first row http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/detail.aspx?KFZID=239636&info=Alfa+Romeo+MiTo+1.4+16V+Impression. It shows me a lot of details (all of them) for that partiular auto that I´d ike to extract into EXCEL.

Then go to the next auto in the table and extract data for it.

Then put evrything into one Excel workbook (does not matter whether one sheet or several)

Of course, it should be done with macro. There are 1016 pages with 10 cars (10160 cars in total) for "Nur aktuelle Modelle" (eng "only current models"). And if I select first "Aktuelle und eingestellte Modelle" (eng. Current and past models) Search then there are 60939 cars (6094 pages with 10 cars).

I tried to write down a macro in VBS for iMacros but failed. Searching for relative posts do not help muxh as I am completely new in this topic and what I found so far does no work well for my case of HTML table.

I would appreciate any suggestions:  how to do it ;
                                     with what software at best  (with a free version to try it once) ;
                                     where to look up an answer for the same problem if there is a solution already

**UPDATE:**

I split my task into several steps.

1) 'LOOP TO EXTRACT LINKS from ONE page

As each page with detailed information differs only wrt KFZID=, I want to extract first all this links from the main page http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/suchergebnis.aspx

With 50 autos per page there are 204 pages

I wrote a Imacro file to extract all 50 HREF from one page with LOOP.

```
'LOOP TO EXTRACT LINKS from each page

VERSION BUILD=10012816
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

'URL GOTO=/http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/suchergebnis.aspx

set !var1 0
add !var1 {{!loop}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=td ATTR=CLASS:tal
TAG POS=R{{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=HREF

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ADACiMacro\1st_15x50 FILE=Extract_LINKS_NEW.csv

'CLICK "PLAY LOOP" WITH MAX=50 AS THERE ARE 50 LINKS ON ONE PAGE
```

? How can I loop over all pages? <=> Do I need a so called NEsted Loop? In VBS or JS, does not matter. What matters, how to run then this script inside iMAcros

2) 'LOOP TO EXTRACT VALUES for ONE KFZID

After I got all links with KFZID (10158 autos=links), I can write a iMacros program to extract information from each of this page separately and put into Excel file

```
'LOOP TO EXTRACT VARIABLE VALUES for each KFZID

VERSION BUILD=10012816
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP no
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

URL GOTO=http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/detail.aspx?KFZID=240009

set !var1 0
add !var1 {{!loop}}

TAG POS={{!var1}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:box-col2 EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ADACiMacro\1st_15x50 FILE=Extract_VALUES_240009.csv

'CLICK "PLAY LOOP" WITH MAX=166 AS THERE ARE 166 VARIABLE VALUES TO BE SELECTED
```

? How can I run it automatically for each KFZID that I need 
(there is no pattern in KFZID numbers, not like from 1-10 continuously, but rather different 6-digits numbers)

So that     URL GOTO=http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/detail.aspx?KFZID=240009 runs for each link (KFZID number)
and outputs SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ADACiMacro\1st_15x50 FILE=Extract_VALUES_240009.csv with unigue name for each link (KFZID number)

Then I can combine all these Excel files together and transpose the value to get a data structure.

I would appreciate any suggestions how to Run LOOPS for each subtask and/or combine them and run together

Comment: You can use iMacros. With little knowledge of JS scripting you can get this done. What you are asking is too complicated to be explained simply. Hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: I add an UPDATE to the task

Comment: Check out answer on your other question.